# date format using CultureInfo wont work

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, c#-4.0, culture

I am trying to change the default date format by the way below but the format wont change and there is no errors

I am excepting to get date in *Arabic format*. What I am getting now is the default system format date like this *(12:00:00 03/01/2011)* while I want to overwrite the system format date

Note: Working under **oracle11g**

```
TBNextDate.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(oraReder[4])
                         .ToString("hh:mm:ss dd/MM/yyyy", new CultureInfo("ar-AE"));
```

Comment: Not an answer but:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hh873ya(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: What do you expect the output to be and what are you getting?  Is `oraReder[4]` a valid date?

Comment: @DStanley I am excepting to get date in Arabic format.. what I am getting now is the default system format date like this (12:00:00 03/01/2011) while I want to overwrite the system format date  ...and yes its valid date

Answer (score 1):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8tfzyc64(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The provider parameter defines the pattern that corresponds to the standard format specifiers, as well as the symbols and names of date and time components.

When you specify a specific format like you do that does not include any name specifiers, the only thing the culture changes is the separator symbol (e.g. `/` or `.`)

If you want to use a date *pattern* specific to that culture, use a [standard format string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx) instead:

```
TBNextDate.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(oraReder[4]).ToString("d", new CultureInfo("ar-AE"));
```

Comment: Okay that's good so far but number we still with default system format... date now appear like (03 يناير, 2011) numbers arr not format and time has been gone i tried to mix between DT or dt or and most of other parameters